# failed to execute postMessage on DOMWindow : target origin

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, cross-domain

i am working on firefox addon. i have 2 scripts filler.js and aws.js

**filler.js**

```
document.getElementById("orderNow").addEventListener("click", function() {

var domain = 'https://www.amazon.com/';
var openWin = window.open(domain);

//message sender
var message = "WS Iron Man";
openWin.postMessage(message,domain); //sending the message

});
```

**aws.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
//alert('page loaded successfully'); //alert function working here
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
    if (event.origin !== "http://localhost/waveapp/includes/pages/order_details.html")
        return;
// alert to check function working or not
var msg = event.data;
    alert(msg);  

}
};
```

**manifest.json**

```
 {

"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Borderify",
"version": "1.0",

"description": "Copy details to amazon.com.",

"icons": {
"48": "icons/border-48.png"
},

"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["filler.js"]
},
 {
  "matches": ["*://*.amazon.com/*"],
  "js": ["aws.js"]
}
],

"permissions": [
"clipboardRead",
"unlimitedStorage",
"storage"
]

}
```

filler.js running in my localhost and aws.js run on amazon.com. this is a firefox extension.

when i run, i am getting error msg in console

"**Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’: The target origin provided (‘https://www.amazon.com’) does not match the recipient window’s origin (‘null’)**"

also getting this msg

"**Storage access automatically granted for tracker “https://www.amazon.com” on “http://localhost”**"

Please help me fix it, i am sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to read into [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

It says and I quote:

> Normally, scripts on different pages are allowed to access each other
>   if and only if the pages they originate from share the same protocol,
>   port number, and host (also known as the "same-origin policy").
>   window.postMessage() provides a controlled mechanism to securely
>   circumvent this restriction (if used properly).

So it is not a CORS error, because those don't apply in this situation.

There are multiple reasons why this might happen:

- You are actually using a different URL than the one provided
- You closed your open window already (window will set everything to null, when it is closed)
- You are doing something in between `window.open` and `window.postMessage`, which might change what is stored inside your reference

Comment: Bro, you're saying this method won't work on localhost but work on live server ?